# Altering data within a constructor java

Tags: java, constructor

I am doing some basic Java programming where i have to create classes which have constructors linked to other class constructors. For example, refer to my following code...

```
public class Friend {

    private String name;
    private Date dateOfBirth;
    private String phoneNum;

    public Friend(String name){
        this.name=name;
        this.dateOfBirth = null;
    }

    public Date setDOB(Date input){
        return dateOfBirth;
    }
}

public class Date {

    final int MINDAYSINMONTH=1; 
    final int MAXDAYSINMONTH=30;
    final int MINMONTHSINYEAR=1; 
    final int MAXMONTHSINYEAR=12;
    private int day;
    private int month;
    private int year;

    //constructor
    public Date(int day, int month, int year){
        this.day=day;
        this.month=month;
        this.year=year;
    }
}
```

I am trying to create a new `Friend`, then alter the `dateOfBirth` value that is within the `Friend` class, like so...

```
Friend trial = new Friend(input);
trial.setDOB(new Date(2, 15, 1991));
```

But my output suggests that i have created a new `Friend` but the `dateOfBirth` didn't change to the values that I supplied above. Could someone please help me understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Please re-read your setter code. Do you assign something to the dateOfBirth field in this setter? Why does it return anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `setDOB` method is wrong - it isn't actually setting anything at all.

Try changing this...

```
public void setDOB(Date input){
    this.dateOfBirth = input;
}
```

You should probably also have a getter method so you can check the value after it has been set...

```
public Date getDOB(){
    return dateOfBirth;
}
```

Comment: -1, giving the answer on homework is counterproductive.  Guide them to the answer.

Comment: I beg to differ on this - I always found the best way to learn Java was to study the code of other people. If you have code from someone else that works correctly, you can study it to see why it works, and thus learn from it. At least that's what I find to be the best. Besides, for a simple setter/getter method, its hardily giving anything away.

Comment: all three of the replies helped me, after reading the first two from  hvgotcodes and sp00m i already got the answer, and reading WATTO's answer help me know if i got it right, i don't see any problem if there are those who give hints and those who guide through the method, both are good ways, btw thanks to all who answered, now i can finally finish my program.

Answer (score 1):

because you `setDOB` method only returns the value

```
 public Date setDOB(Date input){
    return dateOfBirth;
}
```

where is it setting anything?  You should rename that method `getDOB`, since that is what it is doing, and write a proper `public void setDOB` that sets the value.

Answer (score 0):

Clue: your setter takes itself for a getter.